# Takes long time for shutdown after adding to domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, domain

Workstation OS: Windows 7

Domain Controller OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

I have measured the following with a stop watch:

1. When the laptop is in a workgroup, it takes just 17 second to shut down.
2. when I added the same laptop to a domain (corp.abc.com), now it
   takes 1 minutes and 22 second to shut down. (it just shows the shutting
   down screen)

**Why does the shutdown time increase so much when a workstation is added to a domain?**

Note: I have not made any changes on the laptop, nor added any software. I have done the above testing because users start complaining about this after adding their laptop to the domain and takes a long time to shut down. It's happening to all laptops that run Windows 7.

Comment: no there is no logoff scripts / gpo's as well as we don't have roaming profiles.

Comment: Take a look in the error logs on the client machines, specifically group policy processing, this should provide you more insight.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some GPOs that are applying to the client that are doing something like syncing offline files, running logoff/shutdown items, etc.

Run `rsop.msc` on the client in question to see what policies are applying and the difference should become obvious.